# White border on images when clicked :S

Tags: css, image, border

I am currently browser testing a site i am developing but seem to have some strange issue with firefox.

When you click an img you see a white border that surrounds the image.

here is a screen shot.

[a busy cat http://heyfitty.com/white-border.jpg](http://heyfitty.com/white-border.jpg)
![white border on image ]

http://heyfitty.com/white-border.jpg

Thanks guys , appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the following:

```
:focus {
  outline:none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
  border:0;
}
```

Comment: In that case you'll have to set something up on jsfiddle that replicates it ... or add some relevant code to the question.